# How to set the session timer of the SIP.JS library for WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, sipjs

I'm working on a WebRTC project using the Sip.JS library. Everything works as expected for audio and video except one thing that the remote peer automatically drops the session every 30 seconds. Checked the logs and I saw these sort of messages: `Timer M expired for INVITE client transaction` at the caller side and `Timer L expired for INVITE server transaction` at the remote side. Been looking at the Sip.JS doc here `https://sipjs.com/api/0.15.0/` but it appears there is nowhere i can set the session timer. I used to use a different WebRTC JS library called JSSIP and they have a variable called `session_timers` that allows me to enable/disable the session timers. So question: can i disable the session timers in Sip.JS? If I can't how to I trigger the `re-invite` command? Let me know if you need see logs as they are very long.

Answer (score 0):

I found a parameter that seems to be related.
[noAnswerTimeout](https://sipjs.com/api/0.5.0/ua_configuration_parameters/#noanswertimeout)
Try changing this parameter.
If this is the cause, I think the answer process is not working properly.